# Visual Studio 2015 Data Source Configuration Wizard Proplem

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, ms-access-2010

I am using Visual Studio 2015 in order to connect a access database (access 2010) with my windows form app in c#. So for connecting the database into the app, I follow the in instruction in the Microsoft Developer Network: [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171893.aspx).

in the last step for connecting the DB in Visual Studio, A error pop-pup saying that:
[image]

Please help.

**Note:**
that the Database is store in a shared drive in witch the location path has 148 characters (with space):
U:\xxx-xxx\xxx-xxxx\xxx-xxx\xxxx\xx Division\Knowledge Integration Team (KIT)\Knowledge Management\Stakeholders\Stakeholders Intelligence Tool\test

**UPDATE**
Please note that I also split the database (by using a function in access) in order that more than one user can use the app and connect to the DB.

Comment: can you navigate to that shared drive and manually create a file for example right click and create an empty .txt file.. if not then it sounds like a permissions issue..

Comment: Yes I can do that, and I can also, move/delete files in the shared drive

Comment: try a shorter file path.. why is it so long to begin with..? also sounds to me like a network mapping issue do all machines have a `U` Drive on their machine.. or can you get at the actual drive using the double backslash..?

Comment: In short, the place that I'm working has those shared drive in which I can only have access to it. other than that, I cannot create any shared drive. also, I would like that other user can have access to my app.